# Adding intermediate contour values automatically in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, contour

We have 100's of elevation contour shapefiles. In each file, only the 10th contour line has values (200, 450, 700, etc..). We have to attribute values for all the intermediate contour lines (2nd line to 9th, 11th to 19th, etc..). While searching for a solution, happened to see this (link below). ArcGIS CalcContour script(as mentioned in the link) will only work in ArcGIS 9.3. So I couldn't even test the script. Please check the "Limitations script CalcContour" note in this link

https://translate.google.co.in/translate?hl=en&sl=pt&u=http://www.processamentodigital.com.br/2014/04/27/arcgis-9-3-manual-tecnico-para-georreferenciamento-de-um-arquivo-dgn-do-ibge/&prev=search

The script will work like (from what I can see from the YouTube video - link below) we have to snap a point on a contour line and have to draw a line. Finish the editing and enter the increment values. The intermediate lines between the starting and ending point will get the respective values. I've attached a screenshot of that video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uzk5V0MXhUg

[image]

Is it possible to do the same or any plugin available for this kind of work in QGIS ?

This is not duplicate of [How to automatically plot intermediate contours with QGIS, GRASS GIS or SAGA GIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24746/how-to-automatically-plot-intermediate-contours-with-qgis-grass-gis-or-saga-gis?lq=1)

Our intermediate contour doesn't have any values. And we don't have to interpolate any new contour. We have to just assign the respective values for the contours which are plotted. We know the values for, eg: 200m & 450m contour which will be 1st and 10th line.

Comment: I've re-opened your question but I suspect that you would attract more potential answerers to a question that did not require them to watch a video.

Comment: This question is not duplicate, the title sounds like it but if you read it properly it is about populating contour values which is defintely not the same as the  How to automatically plot intermediate contours

Comment: It is difficult to tell what your inputs are or what you want to accomplish.  Are you trying to *create* contour lines from raster data?  Are you trying to *label* contour lines?  Are you trying to *create attributes* for contour line features?

Comment: I feel you need to rewrite this question. I cannot quite grasp it.

Comment: Edited the question. We have to attribute contour lines. Every 10th line has values.

Comment: The plugin DSGTools (https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/DsgTools/) has a tool that does exactly what you need.

Comment: If you have elevation levels, the easiest way is to add a layer of elevation levels and pass their attributes with rounding to the appropriate contours, if not, is this ?...